# Does Primefaces 2.2.1 version supports IE 9 and 10

Tags: primefaces

Currently we are using Primefaces 2.2.1 version for our Web application. But sometimes in IE9 the buttons are not working(when i click on button nothing is happening) and pagination is also not working. Does primefaces 2.2.1 version supports IE 9 and IE 10. If it doesn't support latest versions of IE then which version of Primefaces should we use.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using **really ancient** version of Primefaces. Current version is 4.0.

Aside from the compatibility issues with newest browsers, you should expect more and more problems with finding help. You should **consider** upgrading to versions 3.5 or 4.0.

Please note that from version 3.5 PrimeFaces no longer supports IE 7. IE 8, 9 and 10 are supported.